# How to setup a local hidden service

Tags: onion-services

How do i setup a private hidden service on localhost
My question is how do i setup a private hidden service that can not be accessed by rest of the Tor network i wish to run this hidden service on my computer my reason is i want to test a program i developed that connects to the TOR network and connects to my hidden service i don't want to setup a VPS since i only need the hidden service for a few hours at most

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can either set up a V3 onion service. This will create a 56-character url which will be nearly impossible to find on Tor unless you know the address. Directions are [here](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en).

The other method is to create your own Tor network at home. This may be a lot more work than you are looking to do but it looks like you can [set this up in Docker](https://github.com/antitree/private-tor-network).